# Should a type hinted paramater allow access to subclass methods even if the class methods are not declared in the interface/parent class?

Tags: php, interface, subclass, parent, type-hinting

I noticed that type hinting in PHP does not work the way it does in other object-oriented languages. If a type hinted parameter as a parent-class/interface represents an instance of a sub-class, calling a method on the provided parameter, permits calling both methods defined in the parent and the sub-class. Is this the expected behaviour and if so why?

Let's say there's an interface **A** proposing a method **execute**, and class **B** that implements the interface and defines a new method **done**. If class **C** has a method **doSomething** which takes one parameter of type **A**, it is possible to call both **execute** and **done** methods on the parameter if the object is an instance of class **B**. It would look something like this:

```
interface A
{
    public function execute(): void;
}

class B implements A
{
    public function execute(): void
    {
        echo 'inside execute';
    }
    public function done(): void
    {
        echo 'inside done';
    }
}

class C
{
    public function doSomething(A $obj): void
    {
        $obj->execute(); // This works as expected.
        $obj->done();    // This works even though the object is type hinted as A
    }
}
```

Comment: An interface is a minimum set of requirements. Any implementation of it needs to implement all those requirements but aren't limited to them. The type hint is to make sure the object you get includes the methods from the interface. When you then use `$obj`, you're not using the interface, but the object. If it contains `done()`, and you call that method, it's code wise 100% valid. You could argue it's poor design, but it's not an error.

Comment: @M.Eriksson: You state this as if it was self-evident, but it *is* an error in literally every single other programming language with types. Note that it is perfectly legal to pass in an object of class `D` which only implements `A` and does not have a `done` method, which will lead to a runtime error. According to `doSomething`'s signature, *all we know about `$obj` is that it has an `execute` method*. We don't know that it has a `done` method, and indeed, it does not need to have one, since I can define a class that implements `A` and only has an `execute` method.

Comment: What you should do in this case is to either add the `done()`-method to interface `A`, or create a new interface and use that. Interfaces can also extend other interfaces so you don't need to manually repeat the same signatures all over. If your `doSomething()` expects `done()` to exist, the interface you type hint with should reflect that, or you've basically missed the main point of using interfaces.

Comment: For example, it would be an error in both MyPy and Pyright (the two most popular type checkers for Python), in both Steep and Sorbet (the two most popular type checkers for Ruby), StrongTalk (an optional type system for Smalltalk), TypeScript, Java, C#, C++, Kotlin, Scala, Rust, D, Ceylon, and many others.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - I'm not talking about "every single other programming language". I'm talking about how it works in PHP and why it doesn't throw an error in the posted code.

Comment: @M.Eriksson: "An interface is a minimum set of requirements." – Exactly. And the `doSomething` method *violates* that interface by assuming the existence of methods not guaranteed by that interface. Is it really unreasonable to assume that a type checker is able to catch that? You are stating it as if it were self-evident that this code should work, but that fact is: *it doesn't work*. If I pass an object that implements `A` but has no `done` method, it will error out at runtime *despite the fact that the type checker has verified the program*.

Comment: I've dug through the PHP Language Specification for almost an hour now, and I find it anything but self-evident, to be honest. If I were trying to write a PHP implementation, it would not be clear from the specification what the behavior should be.

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation](https://php.net/manual/language.types.declarations) is not very clear on that [***bold italic*** emphasis mine]:

> Type declarations can be added to function arguments, return values, and, as of PHP 7.4.0, class properties. They ensure that the value is of the specified type ***at call time***, otherwise a TypeError is thrown.

This one sentence is the entirety of the documentation of PHP's type system semantics I could find.

As you can see, this is somewhat vague: what, exactly, is meant by "at call time"?

It appears that the way this is interpreted is that *type checking only happens for arguments in calls*. So, the only type checking that happens is that the argument `$obj` to function `doSomething` is of type `A` when the function is called. Which it is, therefore, there is no error.

The [*PHP Language Specification*](https://phplang.org/) is not much more helpful either. Neither the section on [*Types*](https://phplang.org/spec/05-types) nor the section on [*Functions*](https://phplang.org/spec/13-functions) nor the section on [*Classes*](https://phplang.org/spec/14-classes) answers the question, and [the entire spec does not even contain the word "hint" once](https://phplang.org/?search=hint).

The subsection on [*Type Check Modes*](https://phplang.org/spec/13-functions#type-check-modes) seems to indicate that type checking only happens for function arguments on function calls [***bold italic*** emphasis mine]:

> For coercive mode, if ***the value passed*** is of the same type as the ***parameter***, it is accepted. […]
>
> For strict mode, the ***parameter*** must be exactly of the type that is declared […]
>
> […]
>
> Note that the type check mode is for the function call controleed by the caller, not the callee.

The subsection on [*Function Definitions*](https://phplang.org/spec/13-functions#function-definitions) has this to say:

> By default, a parameter will accept an argument of any type. However, by specifying a *type-declaration*, the types of argument accepted can be restricted. By specifying `array`, only an argument of the `array` type is accepted. By specifying `callable`, only an argument designating a function (see below) is accepted. By specifying `iterable`, only an argument that is of type array or an object implementing the `Traversable` interface is accepted. By specifying *qualified-name*, only an instance of a class having that type, or being derived from that type, are accepted, or only an instance of a class that implements that interface type directly or indirectly is accepted.

There is also [*Return Typing*](https://phplang.org/spec/13-functions#return-typing), of course, but that is not relevant for this example.

However, that is only on the *definition* side. What about the *call* side?

Nope, the section on [*Expressions*](https://phplang.org/spec/10-expressions) is not helpful either.

The subsection on the [*Member Access Operator*](https://phplang.org/spec/10-expressions#member-access-operator) (`->`) in general lists these constraints:

> The *dereferencable-expression* must designate an object or be `NULL`, `FALSE`, or an empty string.
>
> *expression* must be a value of type `string` (but not a string literal) that contains the name of an instance property (**without** the leading `$`) or an instance or static method of that instance’s class type.

And the specific subsection about the [*Member Call Operator*](https://phplang.org/spec/10-expressions#member-call-operator) mention type checking or hinting. *Member Call Operator* just has these constraints:

> The *dereferencable-expression* must designate an object.
>
> Additionally the general function call constraints apply.

The "general function call constraints" are listed in the subsection on the [*Function Call Operator*](https://phplang.org/spec/10-expressions#function-call-operator):

> *callable-expression* must designate a function, by being a value of type string that contains the function’s name, or by being an object of a type that implements `__invoke` method (including `Closure` objects).
>
> The number of arguments present in a function call must be at least as many as the number of non-optional parameters defined for that function.
>
> No calls can be made to a conditionally defined function until that function exists.
>
> Any argument that matches a parameter passed byRef should (but need not) designate an lvalue.
>
> If *variadic-unpacking* is used, the result of the expression must be an array or `Traversable`. If incompatible value is supplied, the argument is ignored and a non-fatal error is issued.

Again, there is no mention of type checking at all, except for the obvious that if *variadic-unpacking* is used, there must be something to unpack.

> Is this the expected behaviour and if so why?

It seems the answer to your first question is "Yes, this is expected behavior". Your second question can only be answered by the person who wrote the specification, unless you are content with the trivial answer "Because the specification says so."

This behavior is certainly surprising: the code in your question is clearly unsafe, but it is not caught by the type system. But this is a good reminder that *the type checker only checks what the type checker is defined to check*. Or, to put it differently: whether or not the type checker considers your program *type-safe* depends on the type system's definition of *type-safe*.

PHP *only* considers passing an argument of the wrong type unsafe, but not calling random methods.

Note that there is nothing about PHP that prevents making this a type error. For example, [*Psalm*](https://psalm.dev/), a third-party static analyzer and type checker for PHP [*does* detect the type error](https://psalm.dev/r/73201e8289):

> ERROR: [UndefinedInterfaceMethod](https://psalm.dev/181) - 25:15 - Method A::done does not exist

Type checkers for other languages can also detect it. For example, in this [Python](https://python.org/) code which is roughly equivalent to your example:

```python
from typing import Protocol


class A(Protocol):
    def execute(self) -> None:
        ...


class B(A):
    def execute(self) -> None:
        print("inside execute")

    def done(self) -> None:
        print("inside done")


def do_something(obj: A) -> None:
    obj.execute()
    obj.done()
```

Both [Mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/) and [Pyright](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright), the two most widely-used type checkers for Python complain:

- *Mypy*: "A" has no attribute "done"
- *Pyright*:

  - Cannot access member "done" for type "A"
    Member "done" is unknown
  - Type of "done" is unknown

Same for [this TypeScript example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4Chm+RADwgQFdIAKASgC5kA3Ae2ABMBuLAXyywQBs4AzgOQAhZMAC2AB14QJEcMPTY8+IqQo16TZphyq8CBiAENZAOl4MA5uQDkoASxSFiZCHcrtVXVc2MQVLSMLHoGhsamFla2DibOyP4gHl76uFxcWDAkIAhgwMaJDADKDPJgABagtgwARgBWtKhaIboqeHX15q4agamqneZJfexcQA):

```typescript
interface A {
    execute(): void;
}

class B implements A {
    execute(): void {
        console.log('inside execute');
    }
    done(): void {
        console.log('inside done');
    }
}

function doSomething(obj: A): void {
    obj.execute();
    obj.done(); // Property 'done' does not exist on type 'A'.
}
```

The same applies to [Ruby](https://ruby-lang.org/). The popular third-party type checker for Ruby, [Sorbet](https://sorbet.org/) detects the error as well:

```ruby
# typed: true

extend T::Sig

module A
  extend T::Helpers, T::Sig
  interface!

  sig { abstract.void }
  def execute; end
end

class B
  extend T::Sig

  include A

  sig { override.void }
  def execute
    puts 'inside execute'
  end

  sig { void }
  def done
    puts 'inside done'
  end
end

extend T::Sig
sig { params(obj: A).void }
def do_something(obj)
  obj.execute
  obj.done # Method done does not exist on A https://srb.help/7003
end
```